# Rsync'ing system, exclude doesn't seem to work

Tags: shell, rsync

I'm trying to make a full filesystem backup of a server through `rsync`, following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync).
I'm using the following command:

```
rsync -aAXH --progress --delete --stats --exclude={\
    "/dev/*",\
    "/proc/*",\
    "/sys/*",\
    "/tmp/*",\
    "/run/*",\
    "/mnt/*",\
    "/media/*",\
    "/lost+found"}\
    /* \
    newserver:/mnt/oldserver-backup
```

However, it still backs up the `/media/x` folders, causing there to not be enough space in the target. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--exclude={x,y,z}` construct only works in bash and needs to be on one line without spaces, only then can bash expand this correctly.

I'd suggest putting the list in a separate file and using `--exclude-from=file`, or doing as megahallon suggests and repeat the --exclude= option part yourself.

Note also that you usually do NOT want `/*` as your source; let rsync take care of recursing, so just specify `/`. that way dot files in / also get copied. I also always add a trailing slash to the destination directory to prevent surprises; a good habit to get into.

Comment: That explains it. I know rsync is picky about slashes, but I copied that part exactly from the archlinux wiki...

Comment: Just because it's in a wiki doesn't mean it's (completely) correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the `rsync` man page

```
   Note also that the --filter, --include, and --exclude options take one
   rule/pattern each. To add multiple ones, you can repeat the options on     
   the command-line, use the merge-file syntax of the --filter option, or  
   the --include-from/--exclude-from options.
```

So in your case you should you probably just want to repeat the --exclude for each directory.